# objective-c getter decorator for boolean values

Tags: objective-c, properties

I was reviewing the [Objective-C Programming Language documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) to get a better understanding of property declaration and implementation. I came across this line, and thought it might be important to the way I code:

> Typically you should specify accessor method names that are key-value
>   coding compliant (see Key-Value Coding Programming Guide)—***a common
>   reason for using the getter decorator is to adhere to the
>   isPropertyName convention for Boolean values.***

Until now, I have simply used this:

`@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL aBooleanProperty;`

But I have always had a sense that this may not be quite right.

I don't understand that last part (highlighted) in the documentation. How does that suggest that I should provide a getter decorator, and what would that do for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that you could use a custom name for a getter like

`@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isValue) BOOL value;`

So to get it you call it like `[someObject isValue]` instead of `[someObject value]`. Apple does this with `NSButton (NSControl)'s` `isEnabled` for example.

Comment: Okay, I think that's pretty clear now. I had it confused with ths topic on the isa property. I made it more complicated in my mind than it is. Thanks.